# WHM nameservers have been changed yet still populating to the old ones

Tags: dns, whm, nameservers

Right, so i've been trying to transfer a website to a different company, and in order for them to host it i have had to change the nameservers to point at them. i have changed them in the WHM settings through the "edit DNS Zone" tab, yet whenever i use something like mxtoolbox it tells me that the old nameservers are still the parent ones. how can i change this or remove them?

i am very new to all of this website hosting intricacies so apologies for any follow up questions if i do not understand :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your domain nameservers at the registrar so they point to the new DNS servers provided by your web hosting company. That's the first step.

Then issue a whois on the domain and check if the correct nameservers appear there in the whois info (you can use a tool like http://whois.domaintools.com). If the nameservers shown there are not the correct ones then you have to change them.